# Vert.x Thread Naming - "vert.x-worker-thread-..."

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x, java-threads, vertx-verticle

I am making a blocking service call in one of my worker verticles that logged a warning. This was "addressed" by increasing the time limit, but, I am more curious about how to read the naming of the thread in the log line - `vert.x-worker-thread-3,5,main`. The full log was this -

```
io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-3,5,main] has been blocked for 64134 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
```

What does the `3,5,main` indicate? Is it some kind of trace from the main verticle? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ThreadName: vert.x-worker-thread-3
- ThreadPriority: 5
- Source: main